# Sets and vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Progressing through my linear algebra learning, I stumbled accross vector spaces. I know that for a set in V to be a vector subspace of V, it must satisfy the 3 following conditions:

i) **0** e U.

ii) if **u1**, **u2** e U, then **u1**+**u2** e U.

iii) if **u** e U, then $\alpha$ **u** e U.

Are the following sets of R^4 subspaces of V?

1. U1 = {(0, 0, 0, 0)}

Here, I can see that first condition is satisfied and that this set is the smallest vector subspace of V. I also know that any linear combinations of scalars will remain in V.

2. U2 = {(*x1*, *x2*, *x3*, *x4*) | *x2x3* = *x1*}

If x2 and x3 belong to V, then their combination will be. This is something I'm not sure to understand, but does it mean that x1 is a combination of x2x3, thus it is also in V?

3. U3 = {(*x1, x2, x3, x4*) | *x1* = *x2* + *x3*, *x2* = 3 *x4*}

*x1* = *x2* + *x3* should work because it satisfies the 2nd condition and 
*x2* = 3 *x4* also because 3 is a scalar that belongs to R^4.

Is this right? What should I add to demonstrate this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are not confusing the closure properties ( ii) and iii) ) with the definition of the subset.

**Question 2.** asks whether $U_2 = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in \mathbb{R}^4 |\ x_2x_3 = x_1 \}$ is a subspace, so you are asked are i), ii), and iii) satisfied?

i) $0\in U_2$ because testing whether $0\in U_2$ is testing whether $x_2x_3 = x_1$ which for $0=(0,0,0,0)$ is testing whether $0\cdot 0 = 0$.

ii) asks  for $x,y\in U_2$ is $x+y\in U_2$.  That is, given $x_2x_3 = x_1$ and $y_2y_3 = y_1$ is $(x_2+y_2)(x_3+y_3) = x_1+y_1$?

iii) is tested similarly using the definitions for $U_2$ and the operations inherited from the original vector space.

You should be able to come up with a counter-example to ii) or iii) for $U_2$.

**Question 3.** follows the same thinking.  The conditions defining $U_3$ are $x_1 = x_2 + x_3$ and $x_2 = 3x_4$.  You need to decide

i) Does $(0,0,0,0)$ satisfy those conditions?

ii) If $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ and $(y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4)$ satisfy the conditions, does $(x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2, x_3+y_3, x_4+y_4)$?

iii) If $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ satisfies the conditions, does $(\alpha x_1, \alpha x_2, \alpha x_3, \alpha x_4)$ for every $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Mndx That's in the right directions, but you want to choose $x$ and $y$ from $U_2$.  $x$ and $y$ have to satisfy the condition(s) defining $U_2$ so you could take $x = (6,2,3,4)$ and $y = (12,3,4,5)$.  This would get you your counter-example.

Comment: For the second question. Let's say I took x = (1, 2, 3, 4) and y = (2, 3, 4, 5), I find that the second condition is not met.

(2+3) (3+4) /= 12

for the third condition, I would have for x ∈ U2  is $\alpha\ x ∈ U2?

Comment: Processing it. will come back to it in a bit.

Comment: @Mndx Once you have a single counter-example to either ii) or iii) you know that the subset is not s subspace and you are done.

Comment: Do we use the same scalary  α for all values?

Comment: Also, not to overload you, but when cooking up counter-examples, simplicity sometimes helps, so I might choose $x = (1,1,1,0)$ and $y=(0,1,0,0)$ for my counter-example to ii).

Comment: Let's say I'm testing the 3rd condition of the 2nd question. I would need to test that αx2αx3 = αx1?

Comment: If you are trying to come up with a counter-example to iii) for $U_2$, you would try to choose particular numbers for $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ in such a way that $x_2x_3 = x_1$ but $\alpha x_2 \alpha x_3 \neq\alpha x_1$ for some number $\alpha$.  I might choose $x = (1,1,1,0)$ to get a simple vector in $U_2$ then choose $\alpha = 2$ so that $\alpha^2 \neq \alpha$ so I would show that $(1,1,1,0)\in U_2$, but $2(1,1,1,0) = (2,2,2,0)$ is not.

Comment: @Mndx Yes! That is exactly what you would test.

Comment: So you would prove it always holds if you think it's true, or cook up a counter-example if you think it is false.

Comment: All clear. Should not have a problem with the third question then.

Answer (score 0):

Every subspace must always have the vector $ 0 $ in it.  Does the set U3 have the vector $ 0 $ in it?

Comment: I would guess so. 0 = 0 + 0 and 0 = 3 * 0. Unless the scalar must also be zero when we are testing this?

Comment: Yes, because for $x =0$, $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 0$, $x_4 = 0$.  So $0=0+0 \Rightarrow x_1=x_2+x_3$ and $0 = 3\cdot 0 \Rightarrow x_2=3x_4$ so $0\in U3$

Comment: Sorry, I mistook the $ x4 $ for a $ \times 4 $...  My bad.

Comment: I'm at fault here, will focus on proper usage of mathjax for future questions.